# max returning 0 excel

Tags: excel, indexing, max, match

New user here.

Problem:
When I use the Max function that references a cell that is using the index function it always returns 0 instead of the highest value.

Backstory:
This is for a home-brew table top RPG game. I am using 5 tables. The first table contains a list of weapons and their properties. The second table lists character stats. The third table contains the character level and class promotion tier. The fourth table is a reference for class promotion tier. The final table has the weapon that my character has equipped with stats of the weapon + the applicable stats.

[Example of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlk7s.png)

The problem arises because as a character increases in class tiers from tier 1 to tier 2, The base stats that the character uses goes from the base 10 to base 5.
My index and match works fine but when I try to add Character attack to Weapon attack to the character equipment depending on class tier I found that the Max portion of the function returns 0 instead of 15.

Here is the function that I have in cell B24:

```
=INDEX(equipmentReference[attack],
       MATCH(characterequpment[[name]:[name]],
             EquipmentReference[[name]:[name]], 0))
 +IF(MAX(Characterlevel[[#All],[tier]]) >= 2, d8, c8)
```

When I do the function in steps it returns:
    8+if(0>=2,15,7.5)--->15.5

it should return:
    8+if(2=>2,15,7.5)--->23

The formula I have the in the character level table for the tier column is:

```
=INDEX(ClassReference[[tier]:[tier]],
       MATCH(CharacterLevel[[class name]:[class name]],
             ClassReference[[class name]:[class name]]))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt get your code working for me because different tablenames, but i think you should lose the [[name]:[name]] and replace with only [name] in every

`=INDEX(Table1[attack];MATCH(Table5[name];Table1[name];0))+IF(MAX(Table3[tier])>=2;Table2[base 5];Table2[base 10])`

this worked on me, output was 23

Comment: Sorry the example that I gave is a simplified version of the data I am working with there are a lot more rows/columns to the table. I keep getting 0 when using the max function on a cell that is using the index function in it. For the character level table, in the tier column put  
  =INDEX(Table5[[#All],[tier]],MATCH(Table3[[#All],[class name]],Table5[[#All],[class name]]),0)                                                                                                Then put the equation you gave me into cell B24.

Comment: Nevermind I think I found a workaround. For the character level table, tier column I used the formula =Value(INDEX(Table5[[#All],[tier]],MATCH(Table3[[#All],[class name]],Table5[[#All],[class name]]),0)). That seemed to fix the problem. I'm not sure why this works though.